# Why isn't this AJAX request working in JSFiddle - while it works fine on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to debug something for over 8 hours, and in order to get a proper example to ask the question of why it's not working, I'm trying to put together a JSFiddle replica, but the AJAX request doesn't seem to make the call. Any help in finding out why would be greatly appreciated!

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqpka/8/

I'm talking about the `$.get()` method.

Comment: It looks like a same origin policy violation to call an external JSON file from  jsfiddle.. It would work correctly from offer-rotator.com

Comment: Wow, that sucks, but thanks. If you want, leave your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: You can test AJAX stuff in JsFiddle - see the "Testing Ajax requests" in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [same origin policy violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to call an external JSON file from jsfiddle. It would work correctly from the domain `offer-rotator.com`.

Answer (score 3):

And another problem might be

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.offer-rotator.com/labs/json.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You are not allowed to send remote ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

Like others have stated, you are running into the cross origin policy limitiation which limits your ajax requests to inter domain requests. You have a few options, you could use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp) or enable [cors](http://enable-cors.org/).